# Create tar.gz file after image style is generated

Tags: 7, media

I would like to achieve this effect: When an style image is saved, a tar.gz file containing that image is generated in the same directory containing the style image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you interested on the code to use to do this, or in a module?

Comment: I do not think it is a module. I can even hack the image module. I do not know where is the function responsible for generating the image.